# Saving data which will be used by some classes in android

Tags: java, android

Whenever my application launches i download some data from internet. I need to save latitude, longitude and one string , So that i can use them in another classes.
Now, How other classes can use that data?
I have two doubles(i.e latitude and longitude), one string.
Kindly tell me some easy way to do that. I will be having at maximum 30 entries of each lat,lon and string. Can i store it in some java class?

Comment: Create a class that stores the data? What have you tried and what issues are you running in to?

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a database? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: I need some suggestions for storing the data without using database. Can we do that by creating some class? Is there such kind of functionality exists in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom datatype class if they all can be packaged together and then have other classes inherit that object.

```
public class LocationData { 
}
```

Have private data members in the class:

```
private double mLat, mLong;
String  mName;
```

Make a constructor of the same name to add the data

```
LocationData(double lat, double longi, String name) {
    mLat = lat;
    mLong = longi;
    mName = name;
}
```

Then you can create functions in that Datatype class to do whatever you want with the data. You can pass this object as a whole or use a get() function to grab certain variables.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this.. I will let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you will never exceed 30 (or some manageable) number of entries, i would suggest you go with `SharedPreferences`. Also, that has the added advantage of being persistent and be easily accessible from any application component.

Comment: could you tell me some efficient way to do that? i have one latitude and corresponding to that i have one longitude and the name of the place.
{latitude,logitude,name},{latitude,logitude,name},.......upto 30